# Cron and request with wp_remote_post

Tags: wp-cron, https, cron, domain, wp-remote-post

I have a problem with a plugin I'm working on, I have implemented a cron that 2 times a day makes a call to update the data, the call is made with the wp_remote_post function.

```
$response      = wp_remote_post(
        ENDPOINT,
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'headers' => array(
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'domainUrl'    => get_site_url(),
            ),
            'body'    => wp_json_encode( $body ),
        )
    );
```

the problem is in the `get_site_url()` function.
For a site that uses the https protocol, `get_site_url()` returns the domain in https when the call is triggered from the frontend or wordpress hooks except cron, instead when `get_site_url()` is triggered by the cron hook it returns **http**.
What may be causing this behavior and how I could fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Is the sites URL set with `http` or `https`? If your site uses `http` but you've relied entirely on a plugin to substitute `http` for `https` after the fact without actually migrating fom http to https then that might cause these issues

Comment: i edited the question, the `get_site_url` sends http only if is triggered by the cron hook

Comment: The documentation says at the top it will return `http` if `is_ssl` returns false, are you absolutely sure that the site URL in the options table has `https`? Have you physically checked the raw value? And that it isn't being filtered or overriden by code? ( Note that the documentation page also has the solution to your question at the very top of the page, then again in the function signature, then again in the parameter list, and several times in the comments at the bottom )

Comment: I found the problem, someone was visiting the site in http even if this works in https, thanks